# Autocomplete hidden files in vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete, hidden-files

In vim, when I use something like `:e` to open files, it doesn't autocomplete files with the hidden prefix `.`. For example, when trying to edit a `.gitignore` file, I have to type out the whole name and can't just go `:e .giti<Tab>`. If I just type `:e <Tab>`, vim only lists non-hidden files.

I've noticed even FuzzyFinder doesn't actually show hidden files when I use `:FufFileWithCurrentBufferDir`.

Is there any way I can enable this?

Comment: FYI, I can use `e .<Tab>` with no problem (Vim 7.4 1-944, ArchLinux).

Comment: Check wildignore. `verbose set wildignore?`

Comment: @VanLaser `e .<Tab>` seems to list hidden directories, but not hidden files (Vim 7.4 1-52, Linux Mint)

Comment: @FDinoff changing `wildignore` seems to work. Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim uses `wildignore` to filter the list of completions when expanding wildcards. Make sure that `.gitignore` doesn't match a file pattern in that list.

`:help 'wildignore'` is copied below

```
                                                'wildignore' 'wig'
'wildignore' 'wig'      string  (default "")
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
                        {not available when compiled without the +wildignore
                        feature}
        A list of file patterns.  A file that matches with one of these
        patterns is ignored when expanding wildcards, completing file or
        directory names, and influences the result of expand(), glob() and
        globpath() unless a flag is passed to disable this.
        The pattern is used like with :autocmd, see autocmd-patterns.
        Also see 'suffixes'.
        Example:
                :set wildignore=*.o,*.obj
        The use of :set+= and :set-= is preferred when adding or removing
        a pattern from the list.  This avoids problems when a future version
        uses another default.
```

To find out where it was last set you can use `:verbose set wildignore?`

Comment: This appears to let hidden dotted files and hidden dotted folders through: `set wildignore+=.*`  But be careful this affects all plugins, who have to contend with this setting.